# Gremlin: How to check if adding an edge would result in a cycle

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

Given a graph, for example:

```
g.addV().property(id,'a').as('a').
  addV().property(id,'b').as('b').
  addV().property(id,'c').as('c').
  addE('knows').from('a').to('b').
  addE('knows').from('b').to('c').iterate();
```

How can I detect that adding an edge would result in a cycle? For example, the following operation would introduce a cycle:

```
g.addE('knows').from('c').to('a').iterate();
```

I want to know about this cycle without actually adding the edge (so I can prevent cycles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea that comes to mind is to check if a path from 'a' to 'c' already exists and only if it does not, add the edge. Using a `coalesce` step, the first traversal inside it that returns a result will be honored. So, if a path to `V('c')` is found then that vertex will be returned. Otherwise the new edge will be created and returned. Hopefully this gives you something to work with even if you end up needing a variation of this approach.

```
gremlin>  g.V('a').
......1>   coalesce(
......2>     repeat(out()).until(hasId('c')),
......3>     addE('knows').from(V('c')).to(V('a')))
==>v[c]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was exactly what I was looking for to point me in the right direction!